# Salesforce 1 not working in mobile chrome browser

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

When i am trying to login in salesforce developer edition in mobile chrome browser both in IOS and android it opens only the desktop version of the site it does not opens the salesforce1 . But when i login using safari its opening salesforce1.Any idea about this issue?

Note : Request Desktop site is not enabled in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monish

Try this.

1. From Setup, click Mobile Administration > Salesforce1 > Settings.
2. Select Enable the Salesforce1 browser app to allow all users in your organization
   to access the app. Deselect this option to turn off access to the app.
3. Click Save.

When this option is turned on, users who log in to Salesforce from a supported mobile browser are always
automatically directed to the Salesforce1 interface. If you want your users to access the full Salesforce site
from mobile browsers instead, deselect this option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Enabling setting with these steps

- From Setup, click Mobile Administration > Salesforce1 > Settings.
- Select Enable the Salesforce1 browser app to allow all users in your
  organization to access the app.
- Deselect this option to turn off access to the app. Click Save.

After enabling, SFDC only enables for Safari not for Chrome, I learned chrome in not a supported browser for iOS (devices)

See below 
[image: Chrome not Listed]

Read more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf1_requirements.htm)